# How to work 16 hours a day?

Tags: fatigue, energy

I'm 27 years old. I work in the computer software industry.
I have a full-time job and I also work on some freelance projects.

I spend around 11 hours on my full-time job and it is a bit stressful (i.e I can only relax for 1 hour).
I commute for 2 hours everyday.

After I go home, I have around 10 hours before i get ready for office again.
If i sleep for 6 hours, i will have 4 hours to work.
If i can concentrate for 4 hours, it would be great. But i cannot do that. I waste time watching TV, eat and sleep. I set an alarm so that i can wake up 4 hours before i start of office, but i cannot wake up.

How can I train myself to stop wasting my time during those hours?
Is it because I'm unhealhty?

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: Well, sleep is vital, don't cut into that. Eating is also very important. As long as you are making enough money to survive at this point, I would say keep doing what you're doing - you need to relax at some point.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a health question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about health

Comment: See [productivity.se]

Comment: http://www.businessinsider.com/yahoo-ceo-marissa-mayer-on-130-hour-work-weeks-2016-8

Comment: In addition to this not being a health-related question: you are asking those who are currently reading posts on stackexchange instead of working. If we knew we would have told you, but... :-)